# Strings are changed strangely when I pass a string from Javascript to Java applet

Tags: java, javascript, string, encoding, applet

I'm making a web IRC client using Javascript and Java applet (for socket. I used Flash before, but since it has strict security restrictions, servers it can connect to is restricted. So I started to use Java applet, which I haven't used before, so I had many problems with that such as using `<applet>`, compiling the applet, and signing jar.), and I have a strange phenomenon.

When a string is passed from Javascript to Java applet (like `irc.sendLine("foobar")`), sometimes characters which code is `65533(�)` or `127`, and sometimes other things like `110` or number in ASCII (`(`) is padded. It could be the encoding problem, but I think it's not, because both the charset used in Java and HTML page are `UTF-8`, and it happens even when the string consists of only alphanumeric.

More strangely, it happens only in Google Chrome. In Firefox, there's no padding (which is OK.)

I modified my Java applet code for debugging the problem.

Below is a part of my code (`traceStr` prints a string to the Javascript console)

```
public void sendLine(String s){
    traceStr(dumpStr(s));
}
private String dumpStr(String s){
    String result = "";
    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
       result += s.codePointAt(i);
        if(i<s.length()-1) result += " ";
    }
    return result;
}
```

and `sendLine` is invoked using JS console, like `irc.sendLine("foobar")`.

Here's some output (adding `0` repeatedly)

```
48 40 65533
48 48 65533 65533 65533 127
48 48 48 65533 65533 127
48 48 48 48 65533 127
48 48 48 48 48 127
48 48 48 48 48 48
48 48 48 48 48 48 48
48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48
48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48
48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48
48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48
48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48
48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48
48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48
48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48
48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 99 111 110 110 101 99 116
48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 65533 65533 65533
48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 65533 65533 65533 127
48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 65533 65533 127
48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 65533 127
48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 127
```

Output for `The quick brown fox`:

```
84 104 101 32 113 117 105 99 107 32 98 114 111 119 110 32 102 111 120 65533 65533 127
```

Output for `天`, `天1`, `天11`, `天111`, and `天地`:

```
22825 65533 65533 127
22825 49 65533 127
22825 49 49 127
22825 49 49 49
22825 22320
```

I'm using Google Chrome 17.0.932.0 and Java 1.6.0_23 on Ubuntu 11.10. This didn't happen when I used Flash. Can anyone identify what I did wrong? From the outputs I guess that there's something wrong related to `UTF-8`, but I don't know anymore...

BTW, Many answers of questions like this I found on SO mentions `ISO-8859-1`, but is it related to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is UTF-16. So conversion from UTF-16 to UTF-8 could be happening with unintended side effects. Escpecialy for characters above 127 decimal.

Comment: I thought about that, but that doesn't explain why outputs in Firefox are OK (it seems that FF uses UTF-16 too). And that doesn't say how to solve the problem... :(

Comment: What about IE and Safari. It could be that Chrome is the exception!

Comment: I tested it on Windows (Google Chrome canary and Firefox), and both works OK. (I didn't test IE but it might be OK) ...So, this is the problem of Google Chrome, I guess... :/

Comment: If it works in IE then how big of a problem is it. IE and FF cover most of the browser market.